# Binding an observable collection to a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, contextmenu

I am trying to make a context menu show up a list of strings. The app contains a datagrid of people who can be Edited,Deleted and Added to a group. I have a class StudentGroup which are different groups a person can be added (One of the Members of StudentGroup is Name). ViewModel retrieves the full list of groups and puts it inside an Observable Collection. I am trying to make the context menu work such that whenever a user right clicks and hover over Add User to -> it opens a side menuitems that contains the Observable Collections's Name string.

This is what I have tried so far by looking up similar questions on StackOverflow, but it hasn't worked for me yet.

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu AllowDrop="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Add User to">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

XAML Code behind View:

```
private TitleViewMode TVM=new TitleViewMode;
public Welcome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _grid1.ContextMenu.DataContext = TVM;
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class TitleViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<StudentGroup> Entries {get;set;}
    private List<StudentGroup> sg1 { get; set;}
    public TitletViewModel()
    {
        sg1 = GetGroups();
        Entries = new ObservableCollection<StudentGroup>(sg1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
<MenuItem Header="Add User to" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"></MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
     </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```